# Why "Does anyone still use flowcharts?" has been closed?

Tags: discussion

[This](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/107227/does-anyone-still-use-flowcharts) question has been closed as being not constructive. The main point is:

> Does anyone still use flowcharts and if so, under what circumstances?

This question is answerable and relevant answers can include pointers to contemporary development methodologies that uses flowcharts. I fail to see how it is  non constructive. Can someone shed a light on this issue?

Comment: I've edited the title and body of your question to (hopefully) make it a little more focused, and cast a reopen vote.  But it looks like your question has already attracted some pretty good answers.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that **as phrased** the question is a poll. If you check the [What kind of questions should I *not* ask here?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask) section of the FAQ you'll see the following:

> **avoid** asking subjective questions where …
>
> - every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?”
> - your answer is provided along with the question, and you expect more answers: “I use ______ for ______, what do you use?”
> - there is no actual problem to be solved: “I’m curious if other people feel like I do.”

The question fails (as I see it) because the poster doesn't have a problem they're trying to solve, every answer is fundamentally equally valid ("Yes I still use flow charts", "No I don't use flow charts any more") and it answered the question in the question.

Also check out the blog post on [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) linked to from the close reason. This goes into more details about the type of open ended question that makes a good question.

A more useful question *might* be something along the lines of

> Are flowcharts still useful with modern software development techniques and methodologies.

Though I'm sure someone else could phrase that a lot better.

Comment: It's not my question actually, I just though that it was good enough to be kept open. After I casted a reopen vote I asked here because I couldn't see why it was closed in the first place. Thank you for clarifying.

Comment: @Vitor - sorry I should have checked. I'll correct the answer.